# How to drag an image from FireFox and keep original name

Tags: firefox

How can I drag and drop an image that I am viewing in FireFox, directly to a folder, and not having it being saved with default name, e.g.: url.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just found this and although it might look obvious, it took me a long time to understand it, but I actually never searched for any answer to this so I simply draged the images and then changed their name on my PC.

The solution is really, really simple:

This only happens when the image you are viewing is bigger than your actual window size, so FireFox adjusts the image automatically. In order for you to save the image with original name, you just click one time when viewing it in FireFox window, so you can view it in it's original size, and then you can drag and drop it in a folder, no problems. :D

Hope this helps someone... at least someone that cares to search (something I haven't done :P)

Comment: You'll be glad to know this helped immensely. That'll teach me to keep my windows stuck to the side of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out it doesn't always works, but at least it helps... Thanks for your comment. :)

Comment: Yeah, there's more to it than just that. I did however find that if you left click on the image before trying to save it you'll save the original (I think, I can't remember).